# Why Does Float Make Image Disappear?

Tags: html, word-wrap

[image]

Hey there, my image disappear when i use a float for textwrapping. I have tried to add

```
.overflow: hidden;

.clear{clear:both;
```

and define exact size of image but non of it helps.

CSS

```
    <style>
h3 {font-family: "futura-pt";
color:#a3a3a3;
font-size:16px}

  p class="content" {font-family: "proxima-nova";
color:#a3a3a3; 
font-size:16px;
}

.clear { clear:both; }
.textwrap {
float: right;
  margin: 10px;}

img class="textwrap" {
    width: 600px;
    height: auto;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .left, 
    .right {
        float: none;
        width: auto;
    }
}


</style>
```

HTML

```
<div class="accordion">
 <h3>More about Ermengildo Zegna</h3>

   <div>
      <div>
        <div>
         <img class="textwrap" src="http://madsschou.com//stock11/zegnabook.jpeg" alt=""> 
        </div>

        <div>
       <p class="content">Der Name leitet sich vom Gründer des Unternehmens, dem Schneider und Unternehmer Ermenegildo Zegna (1892–1966) ab, der 1910 als 18-Jähriger in die Stoffweberei seines Vaters Angelo Zegna, der eigentlich gelernter Uhrmacher war und eine kleine Firma mit vier Webstühlen aufgebaut hatte, in Trivero einstieg. Noch im gleichen Jahr gründete Ermenegildo - als jüngstes von 10 Kindern - die Lanificio Zegna (dt. Wollweberei Zegna), übernahm nach dem Tod des Vaters 1923 die Fabrik und begann mit der Produktion hochwertiger Stoffe.[1] Bis zum Jahr 1930 wuchs das Unternehmen bereits auf 1000 Mitarbeiter an und produzierte vorwiegend feine Anzugstoffe. Bereits 1938 wurden Zegna-Stoffe in die USA exportiert und nach dem Zweiten Weltkrieg in 40 Länder geliefert. Mit dem Tod von Ermenegildo Zegna 1966 übernahmen dessen Söhne Aldo (1920–2000) und Angelo (* 1924) den Betrieb. Ab 1968 wurden auch eigene Anzugskollektionen angeboten, zunächst nur in Konfektionsgrößen und ab 1972 schließlich auch als Maßanzüge (Su Misura). Bis heute produziert Zegna ausschließlich Herrenmode. Im Zuge der Expansion des Unternehmens Ende des 20. Jahrhunderts wurde allerdings 1999 das Luxus-Label Agnona (1953 in Agnona gegründet) zugekauft, das ausschließlich Damenmode produziert.</p>   </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: I see your image just fine with the code you posted:  https://jsfiddle.net/dsw0pemg/  Is this the same code you're running that exhibits the problem?

Comment: It's code injected in squarespace website builder. https://www.dropbox.com/s/g0qiwly1jp1ntax/Screenshot%202016-05-27%2016.23.38.jpg?dl=0
I'll try to ask squarespace as well.